# how can i use List.exists after a List.map without an extra let binding?

Tags: f#

```
type ProcessAttachmentResult = ValidAttachment | InvalidAttachment

let processAttachment ( attachment : Attachment ) =
    if attachment.Name ="test.txt" then
       printfn "%s valid" 
       ValidAttachment
    else 
       printfn "%s invalid" attachment.Name
       InvalidAttachment

// attachments is of type List<Attachment>
let processedAttachments = attachments |> List.map processAttachment

// ProcessAttachmentResult list
let emailContainsValidAttachments = 
   List.exists ( fun r -> r = ValidAttachment) processedAttachments

match emailContainsValidAttachments with
| true -> move email toProcessedFolder 
| _ -> move email toErrorFolder
```

How can i change the last two let bindings and match to a single binding?

i tried

```
attachments |> List.map processAttachment |> List.exists (fun r -> r = ValidAttachment)
```

but this gives:

> This expression was expected to have type `ProcessAttachmentResult list` but here has  type `bool`

Comment: Your approach is perfectly fine. Did you redefine `List.exists` or `List.map` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pad mentioned in a comment, there is nothing wrong with your approach. You must have accidentally redefined some built-in function (like `List.exists`). To check this, try opening a new F# Script File and paste the following code.

It is essentially your code with the missing declarations added and it type-checks just fine:

```
type ProcessAttachmentResult = ValidAttachment | InvalidAttachment 
type Attachment = { Name : string }
let attachments = [] 
let move a b = ()
let email = 0
let toProcessedFolder = ""
let toErrorFolder = ""

let processAttachment ( attachment : Attachment ) = 
    if attachment.Name = "test.txt" then 
       printfn "%s valid"  // TOMAS: Minor issue here - you missed the argument
       ValidAttachment 
    else  
       printfn "%s invalid" attachment.Name 
       InvalidAttachment 

// attachments is of type List<Attachment> 
let processedAttachments = attachments |> List.map processAttachment 

// ProcessAttachmentResult list 
let emailContainsValidAttachments =  
   List.exists ( fun r -> r = ValidAttachment) processedAttachments 

match emailContainsValidAttachments with 
| true -> move email toProcessedFolder  
| _ -> move email toErrorFolder  

// TOMAS: No problem here - this type-checks without errors
attachments 
|> List.map processAttachment 
|> List.exists ( fun r -> r = ValidAttachment)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need:

```
let emailContainsValidAttachments = 
    List.exists ( fun r -> r = ValidAttachment) (List.map attachments processAttachment)
```

The argument order, for some reason, is different in `exists` vs. `map`.